# ASM Skip Code for some Methods

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Is there a way to tell ASM that I *don't* want to use the `SKIP_CODE` option for a particular method? For example, if I have a very large class like this:

```
public class Large
{
    public void doManyThings() { /* ... */ }

    public void methodWithLongBytecode() { /* ... */ }

    public @inline void inlinableMethod() { /* ... */ }
}
```

My compiler spends a lot of time on the methods whose code it doesn't need, as they can't be inlined anyway. However, I still want to be able to read the `inlineableMethod` so the compiler can inline it's bytecode into the caller. Is there a way to temporarily 'disable' the `SKIP_CODE` flag during class reading using **ASM 5.0.3**?

Comment: What stops you from visiting a class two times, first with `SKIP_CODE`, then, as you know for which methods to return a non-`null` method visitor, without it?

Comment: I don't know if that would save me any time, and I highly doubt it.

Comment: Well, you said “*My compiler spends a lot of time on the methods whose code it doesn't need*” and you are bothering with `SKIP_CODE`. That all makes sense only if you assume that processing the code of methods you don’t want to inline has any significant impact on the performance. If it has, visiting two times may be an option. If it doesn’t, visiting once without `SKIP_CODE` is the way to go. If it’s impact is unclear, it’s time to start profiling the application…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. If you look at the [source code of a ASM `ClassReader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ow2.asm/asm/5.0.3/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.java#ClassReader), you can see that the `SKIP_CODE` attribute is interpreted once and then stored within a local variable. Therefore, even by changing the flag reflectively, you can either skip all or no methods. However, by returning a `null` from `visitMethod`, you can instruct to not interpret a method altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately, returning `null` does not work for me, as I need to know the annotations and parameter names.

Comment: Then, I am afraid, you are out of luck. You would have to modify the original source code for getting this working.